# Keydown only with real characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keydown

simple question:
I have input fields with inside-labels! Just like the search-box on this site in the upper right corner. When I start typing the label inside it is hidden.

For accessability reasons I have real  tags absolutely positioned behind the actual input field. Therefore I just add a class `fill` to the inputfield so the background color is no longer transparent.

```
inputs.keydown(function (e) {
     $(this).addClass(fill);
});
```

Everything works fine except for a little flaw.
Whenever I focus the input field and hit a key like "Shift" "Ctrl" or "CMD" the label disappears. However this is no input yet!

Any idea how to do so?

```
inputs.keydown(function (e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {        
            case 13: // Enter
            case 16: // Shift
            case 17: // Ctrl
            case 18: // Alt
            case 19: // Pause/Break
            case 20: // Caps Lock
            case 27: // Escape
            case 35: // End
            case 36: // Home
            case 37: // Left
            case 38: // Up
            case 39: // Right
            case 40: // Down

            // Mac CMD Key
            case 91: // Safari, Chrome
            case 93: // Safari, Chrome
            case 224: // Firefox
            break;
        }

        $(this).addClass(fill);
    });
```

These would be all the keycodes where I don't want to blur the label! Just when typing real characters the fill-class should be added. 
Btw. is there a better syntax to write those switch statements with all the cases?

Comment: The jQuery event object http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ has `altKey`,`ctrlKey`,`metaKey`,`shiftKey` properties that you may want to inspect and handle too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would only execute the addClass when no case is hit:

```
inputs.keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {        
        case 13: // Enter
        case 16: // Shift
        case 17: // Ctrl
        case 18: // Alt
        case 19: // Pause/Break
        case 20: // Caps Lock
        case 27: // Escape
        case 35: // End
        case 36: // Home
        case 37: // Left
        case 38: // Up
        case 39: // Right
        case 40: // Down

        // Mac CMD Key
        case 91: // Safari, Chrome
        case 93: // Safari, Chrome
        case 224: // Firefox
        break;
        default:
          $(this).addClass(fill);
        break;
    }
});
```

But since you are using jquery and want a smaller solution try this:

```
inputs.keydown(function (e) {
  if($.inArray(e.keyCode,[13,16,17,18,19,20,27,35,36,37,38,39,40,91,93,224])) return;
  $(this).addClass(fill);
});
```

Comment: Don't do if($.inArray(item, array))
Do if($.inArray(item, array) !== -1)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) instead if you're dealing with character inputs. It already takes care of ignoring *most of* the keys you want to avoid. It does get triggered at `Enter`, but you can easily account for that in the same manner already proposed here.

```
$("input").keypress(function (e) {
    if( e.which == 13 ){ return false; }
    $(this).addClass(fill);
}
```

Comment: And does not seems to be reliable for arrows either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347269/jquery-keypress-arrow-keys

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the text length before and after the key press and see if there is a  difference. If there is, it was a real char or a paste event, in which case you need to apply the background color.

i.e. Something like:

```
var dataLength = 0;

// use keyup instead of keydown to ensure that we catch the event after the data has been entered
inputs.keyup(function (e) { 
   if($(this).val().length != dataLength) $(this).addClass(fill);

   ... 

   dataLength = $(this).val().length;

   // re-apply placeholder text if no text
   if(dataLength == 0) $(this).removeClass(fill);
}
```

Still better, use the jQuery textchange event plugin. http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event