# How to get right, left, up and bottom arrow key value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have used the below code, and whenever click the arrow key (left, right, up, down) I get the key value is "0". Can anyone can help on this?

```
 $(document).keypress(function (e) {

 alert("key value: " + e.which); 

  });
```

How to get (Up, Down, Right, Left) arrow key value when `keypress`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Keypress Arrow Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347269/jquery-keypress-arrow-keys)

Answer (score 5):

Use `keydown` insted of `keypress`

```
 $(document).keydown(function(event){    
    var key = event.which;                
            switch(key) {
              case 37:
                  // Key left.
                  break;
              case 38:
                  // Key up.
                  break;
              case 39:
                  // Key right.
                  break;
              case 40:
                  // Key down.
                  break;
        }   
  });
```

Comment: jQuery ensures that `event.which` works on all browsers (including those that natively support `event.keyCode` and not `event.which`): http://api.jquery.com/event.which.

Comment: ya its better , added in answer

Answer (score 2):

In many browsers the `keypress` event doesn't recognise the arrow keys (nor keys like "shift", "del", "esc", etc. If you want to capture those key presses, you'll need to use `keydown` or `keyup` instead:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    alert("key value: " + e.which); 

});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/8q7Mu/).

As for the right, left, up and down arrow keys, those are:

```
left     37
up       38
right    39
down     40
```