# Keydown on table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following Javascript that if I should press the down arrow and the cursor will go down to the next row. I can't seem to make that happen. Any suggestions?

**jQuery**

```
$('td').keypress(function(evt){
    if(evt.which == 40){
        event.preventDefault();
        var cellindex = $(this).index()
        var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() + 1
        $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr><td contenteditable>My_Name</td><td>Surname</td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable>My_Name2</td><td>Surname2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Guessing this should be better with an input rather than contenteditable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Keypress Arrow Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347269/jquery-keypress-arrow-keys)

Comment: should event.preventDefault() be evt.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('td').keydown(function(evt) {
        if(evt.keyCode == 40) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var cellindex = $(this).index()
            var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() + 1
            $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
        }
    });
});
```

or can use for down and up key event in this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('td').keydown(function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode == 40){
        event.preventDefault();
        var cellindex = $(this).index()
        var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() + 1
        $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
    }else if (evt.keyCode == 38){
            event.preventDefault();
        var cellindex = $(this).index()
        var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() - 1
        $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq('+rowindex+') td:eq('+cellindex+')').focus()
    }
})
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgtc83ts/1/)

Comment: A little explanation of your solution would be helpful.

Comment: use on keydown for key event and event.keyCode =40 this code for down arrow, you need get on keyDown and creat if keydown code ==40 then next td

Comment: `modifier and non-printing keys ... trigger keydown events but not keypress events` -- [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: That Worked for Regular HTML file for me. I use smarty/php combo and it didn't seem to work. i put the same script in a .tpl and it didn't work. i know the Jquery is being accessed because another function works.

Comment: It did not. I'm wondering if smarty template for some reason is not seeing the code

Comment: sorry but your question fir jquery keypress and not fir smarty thmeplate